# Formula for calculating profit

Tags: math-history

I have 100 dollars. If I add 50% every day, on the first day, 150 dollars, the second day will be 225 dollars, and on the third day 337 dollars. Is there a formula for obtaining 337 dollars directly?

Comment: Hint:  Letting $a_n$ be the amount of money you have at the end of day $n$, we have $a_n=1.5\times a_{n-1}$

Comment: @lulu Can I do without a recursive formula?

Comment: @MCCCS thanks alot, excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula:

$$a_n=(1.5)^n\cdot 100$$

On the third day:

$$a_3=(1.5)^3\cdot 100$$

$$a_3=(3.375)\cdot 100$$